# Failed Upload Image on Laravel Deployed in IIS Server

Tags: laravel, iis, file-upload

I deployed my laravel project on IIS Server, when I try upload image I get
`mimeType:"aplication/octet-stream"`

here my code in contoller
`dd($request->file('background'));`

I added inbound rule like this
[image: inbound rule]

but not work. How to solved this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the error logs for a specific error message?

Comment: Did you get any error messages? you can also refer to this link about how to deploy Laravel to IIS. [https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a2199/how-to-build-and-deploy-laravel-to-iis.aspx](https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a2199/how-to-build-and-deploy-laravel-to-iis.aspx).